# Laravel: showing selected value in edit form

Tags: php, database, laravel

I added a drop down list in the user registration form in Laravel. Now I want to make a form to edit it but I'm stuck.

What I did is I made a drop down list which a new user can register where he/she lives. I used a list of cities(pref.php) in the configuration folder to make this drop down list. I want the user to be able to see the cities that they have registered default when opening the edit form and then change it or leave it alone but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Here are my codes.

**editprofile.php**

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('patch') }}
    <p>
        <label><b>name</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value='{{ $user->name }}'><br>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>location</b><br>
            <select type="text" name="location" value="{{ $user->prefName }}">
                @foreach(config('pref') as $key => $score)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $score }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>mail adress</b><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value='{{ $user->email }}'><br>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>profile image</b><br>
            <input type="file" name="profile_image"><br>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    <input type='submit' value='edit' class="btn btn-primary mt-3">
</form>
```

**ProfileController.php**

```
public function edit()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('profile.editprofile', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function update(ProfileRequest $request, User $user)
{
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->location = $request->location;

    if ($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {
        Storage::delete('public/profile_image/' . $user->profile_image);
        $path = $request->file('profile_image')->store('public/profile_image');
        $user->profile_image = basename($path);
    }

    $user->update();

    return redirect('/profile');
}
```

**pref.php**

```
<?php

return array(
  '0' => 'not selected',
  '1' => 'New York', 
  '2' => 'Los Angeles', 
  '3' => 'Dallas'
);
```

I thought [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268471/getting-selected-option-on-edit-form-in-laravel) had a similar problem but it was a little different.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have to make the option that matches the one they have set as "selected"

Comment: Hey there,
I tried to do that but it was a little bit tricky when I have the options(New York, Los Angeles etc,) in another file. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you are referencing location as `$user->location` in controller's update function but as `$user->prefName` in edit form. which one is actually your database column name??

Comment: Hi, the column name in my DB is “location”. prefName is for Laravel to convert id into city names(like '1' => 'New York' ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make an option selected you have to put selected property in that option. putting value on select won't work. you can do it like

```
<select type="text" name="location">
    @foreach(config('pref') as $key => $score)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ $user->location == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $score }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Hi!
I tried your code and it's working now.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your edit form you had a particular user information by it ID in one array after that you get the user into a edit page right, using that array you can check with option box like below example

```
<select type="text" name="location" value="{{ $user->prefName }}">
@foreach(config('pref') as $key => $score)
   <option <?php echo($get_array_by_user_id->table's_exist_location_value == $key) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="{{ $key }}">{{ $score }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

I think it is working exactly to you : - )

Thank You,